# Connection Timeout laravel email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am using go daddy cpanel email to send an email using laravel. This is the code i am using:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=sg3plcpnl0013.prod.sin3.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Contact Us"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=memail@mail.com
```

Error:
Swift_TransportException
Connection to tcp://sg3plcpnl0013.prod.sin3.secureserver.net:465 Timed Out

Answer (score 0):

If your Laravel hosted on the godaddy you may just use directyle the sendmail function for your Email service notifications.

Comment: @joem They mean you should be able to do `MAIL_DRIVER=mail` or `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`.

Comment: @joem yes. ceejayoz is technically correct on that. In the mail.php config file of laravel here our the possible services you can use. 

Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses" "sparkpost", "log", "array"

if you're using cpanel hosting or any sharedhosting with built in email service. you can directly use the 'sendmail' as a MAIL_DRIVER

Answer (score -3):

please change APP_URL=http://localhost to 
URL=http://your-ip-address

it's in the .env
sorry my english is not good

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with the error OP describes.